# Foursquare, notifications

Tags: foursquare

everyone!
I need help.
Is there possible, to send notifications, or messages to friends using the Foursquare API?
I need application, which will inform my friends about something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. The actions exposed for Users via the Foursquare API are approve,deny,request,setpings,unfriend and update (the user photo), according to the [API docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users).

What you might try to do is access each friend's `contact` property (see [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user)) to get the contact information (email, phone, twitter or facebook) and use that to contact them.